# how to greet somebody in a guestbook

Tags: salutations

I would like to send my French host family a guestbook for their toilet as a whimsical gift. I would like to inscribe something on the first page to inspire people to write in. I need to decide what kind of words would be appropriate. What would you advise me to write?

"chers visiteurs des toilettes" ?

Is this correct? How would you greet them?

[Here's an example of a **Bathroom Guest Book**](http://theawesomer.com/bathroom-guest-book/250476/) from *The Awesomer*.

Comment: I know it's a joke but I wonder if a "*Livre d'or des toilettes*" would really be appreciated as a present by most French people unless perhaps, your host family is actually in Groland ;-)

Comment: There is already at least one of these in French (here)[http://www.e-leclerc.com/espace+culturel/produit/le-livre-d-or-des-toilettes,28590390/#onglet_fiche_detaille] though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's correct ! Nothing more to say.

But you can also write :
" Bienvenue dans les toilettes ! "

Edit: Because [Lambie](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/9299/lambie):

You can as well use " Bienvenue aux toilettes ! ", and it's grammatically more correct than the previous sentence.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49778/discussion-on-answer-by-shudent-how-to-greet-somebody-in-a-guestbook).